# Windows form not responding: How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, setup-project

I create a windows service and a setup project.

During the installation of the windows service, I add a windows form which allow the user to upload a file in the project folder but when I click on the button to upload the file my windows form is always on state **not responding**

[image: not responding]

**ProjectInstaller of my windows service**

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);

    Form1 validationForm = new Form1();
    validationForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Windows form**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        //fileDialog.Filter = "Dat files |*.dat";
        fileDialog.Multiselect = false;

        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var path = fileDialog.FileName;
            Process.Start(path);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occured", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Not Responding" happens when the Form loads or When you click the `Button` in the form

Comment: @SH7 When I click on the button

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with your code. Please remove statements one at a time until you isolate the offending line, then let us know which one that is, perhaps then we can have some good answers for you.

Comment: Did you miss any lines of code, After selecting the file are you just opening it or are you uploading it somewhere ? what happens after that ?

Comment: @Clint I didn't miss lines of code, for the moment I only do that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have not responding when I do OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

Comment: Could it be that your thread is not using the Single Threaded Apartment model, STA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task = new Thread(() => GetFile());
    task.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    task.Start();
    task.Join();
}

private static void GetFile()
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        //fileDialog.Filter = "Dat files |*.dat";
        fileDialog.Multiselect = false;

        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var path = fileDialog.FileName;
            Process.Start(path);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occured", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could open a document to select the file but after select the file and click on ok I have a not responding again.

Comment: Is the Process.Start accurate, because it works fine for me. Or do you actually have code that does something else?

Answer (score 4):

I think `Process.Start(path);` block UI thread.
Try to use `Task.Run(() => Process.Start(a));` instead.

Comment: I still have the issue.

Comment: I think you will need to wrap the whole thing in a Task.Run

Comment: @RyanThomas all the content of my try ?

Comment: @user10863293 what issue do you have with `Task.Run(() => Process.Start(a));`? please show your modified code

Comment: I think the problem is before the Process.Start() I think the not responding starts trying to use OpenFileDialog.

Comment: @oleksa I still have not respondig

Answer (score 2):

*Your UI is locked up due to a long running process which is why you see "Not responding"*

Mark your Click `Async`:

`private async void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)`

and

```
 await Task.Run(() =>
 {
    //Insert the long running stuff here
    Process.Start(path);            
 });
```